# Jquery when appending text to html charset utf8 not working

Tags: jquery, utf-8, character-encoding

When I'm passing information to a div inside html the charset utf 8 is not recognized and it comes with interrogation points inside the text.
Is there a way to force the charset utf 8 inside jquery so all the text passed by the script comes in the correct charset?

Edit:
I think I set all the charsets I could inside all my files:
HTML

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.9.0.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="message_validator.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="error_display" charset="utf-8"></div>
<form charset="utf-8">
<input type="text" id="name" class="textbox" name="name" minlength="2" maxlength="12" />
</form>
</body>
```

JQUERY

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).load("Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    $('.submit').click(function(){
        var errorlist = [];
        errorlist.length = 0;

        errorlist.push("- Tem de preencher os campos obrigat&#243;rios.");

         if(errorlist.length >= 1){
            $('.error_display').animate({'height':errorlist.length*20}, {queue:false, duration:500});
            for(var i = 0; i < errorlist.length; i++) {
                $('.error_display').append(errorlist[i]+"<br/>");
            }

         }
    });
});
```

Comment: You cannot use jQuery.load() like this. Please paste your actual code.

Answer (score 2):

Put your text with the correct characters and then try to decode it like this:

```
errorlist.push(decodeURIComponent(escape("- Tem de preencher os campos obrigatórios.")));
```

Check also those examples to encode/decode the text [here](http://rbalajiprasad.blogspot.com.es/2012/09/jquery-utf8-encode-and-decode.html)

Answer (score 1):

This should not be an issue. Make sure your page is set to use UTF8 in the meta tag.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Also make sure the source of this text (if it's server-side, you did not specify in OP) is sending it to you as UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that one should be aware of, is taht the encoding of the script file itself can result in this error. Make sure that your script file is encoded correctly. In Visual Studio, this is done by:

1. Opening the file and do a "Save as"
2. click the chrevon down next to the Save button and choose "Save with encoding"
3. Choose your required encoding

[image]

It varies a bit from IDE to IDE, but the gist is the same